# Celery link_error raise NotRegistered exception

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a client celery application issuing task for a worker (using Redis), it's working ok. Both client and worker applications uses the same config :

```
app = Celery('clientApp', broker='redis://redis:6379/0',backend='redis://redis:6379/0')
# Listen to queue2

app = Celery('workerApp', broker='redis://redis:6379/0',backend='redis://redis:6379/0')
# Listen to queue1
```

Now I want to execute handler on success or error, so I used something like this :

```
task = Signature('mytask', queue='queue1')

task.apply_async(
    link=Signature("handle_success", queue='queue2'),
    link_error=Signature("handle_error", queue='queue2'))
```

This call `handle_success` correctly on success but do not call `handle_error` when `mytask` raise an `Exception`. Can you see any reason why ? The goal here would be that the **client** to execute `handle_error` on task failed by the worker (like it does execute `handle_sucess` when the worker task complete sucessfully).

`celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'handle_error'`

I have no error or info messages when celery applications starts, backend is the same url for both apps and `handle_success` / `handle_error` correctly shows up in registered tasks for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using the hack listed in this [article](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/celery-callbacks-when-tasks-succeed-or-fail-using-links/).

If the `link_error` argument is a single task, it will get executed by the worker directly (unlike `link`), one way to force the worker to send the task to the client is to use a chain.

```
from .tasks import error_callback
app.send_task("system_b.foo", link_error=(error_callback.si() | error_callback.si())
```

Or use a dummy task plus helper functions to make it more clear, see article.